# View to count columns and convert values from single row to multple rows

Tags: sql-server-2008, view

I have this table `T` in SQL Server 2008, I need to create a view which converts result of each row into multiple rows. Below is an example of target view.

Please help

Current table T

```
EmpID   EmpName State   City
---------------------------------
1234    aaaa     NY     NY
6789    bbbb     FL     Orlando
```

Target View :

```
EmpID   ColumnName      ColumnValue
-----------------------------------
1234    EmpName         aaaa
1234    State           NY
1234    City            NY
6789    EmpName         bbbb
6789    State           FL
6789    City            Orlando
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE VIEW yourView AS
SELECT EmpID, 'EmpName' AS ColumnName, EmpName AS ColumnValue
FROM T
UNION ALL
SELECT EmpID, 'State', State
FROM T
UNION ALL
SELECT EmpID, 'City', City
FROM T
```

Then provide the ordering when you actually select from this view:

```
SELECT t.EmpID, t.ColumnName, t.ColumnValue
FROM yourView t
ORDER BY t.EmpID,
         CASE WHEN t.ColumnName = 'EmpName' THEN 1
              WHEN t.ColumnName = 'State'   THEN 2
              WHEN t.ColumnName = 'City'    THEN 3 END
```

Comment: I'm getting errror "ORDER BY clause is invalid in views , inline functions , derived tables , subqueries and common table expressions , unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified "

Comment: @AHS I updated my answer.  Generally a view cannot use `ORDER BY`.  Instead, provide the ordering you want at the time you actually select.